# How to bind NSDictionary data to table view in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

I have used the below code to convert the JSON data(from SOAP service) to `NSDictionary`.

```
-(void)retriveFromSYSoapTool:(NSMutableArray *)_data{
    NSLog(@"data: %@",_data);
    NSArray *value = [_data valueForKey:@"GetDemoDataResult"];
    NSError *error;
    NSData *objData = [value[0] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",json);
}
```

**Output**

```
2017-04-04 13:03:51.085 SoapService[18444:588594] (
        {
        firstName = "1 Jhon";
        lastName = Macay;
    },
        {
        firstName = "2 William";
        lastName = Proter;
    },
        {
        firstName = "3 Joe";
        lastName = Root;
    },
        {
        firstName = "4 Brendon";
        lastName = Haejoy;
    },
        {
        firstName = "5 Jhon";
        lastName = Snow;
    },
        {
        firstName = "6 Theon";
        lastName = Greyjoy;
    }
)
```

Do I need to convert this to any other? or how could I bind the above output in UITable​View?

Comment: NSDictionary  has no order, so append your dictionary to array, and load the array in tableview and finally access your string ike cell.textlabel.text = yourarrayname[indexpath.row][@"firstName"];

Comment: I believe your JSON is actually an array, not a dictionary. You can check by inspecting json using the debugger, or by logging the class of the object. Assign it to a `NSArray *`, and then use it in your tableview data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this

Declare jsonArray in your .h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)  NSMutableArray *jsonArray;
```

Add below line viewDidLoad

```
self.jsonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


 -(void)retriveFromSYSoapTool:(NSMutableArray *)_data{

    NSLog(@"data: %@",_data);

    NSArray *value = [_data valueForKey:@"GetDemoDataResult"];

    NSError *error;

    NSData *objData = [value[0] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    NSLog(@"%@",son);

   [self.jsonArray addObject:[[json objectForKey:@"firstname"]stringByAppendingString:[json objectForKey:@"lastname"]];

   [tableViewName reloadData];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return self.jsonArray.count;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

}

cell.textLabel.text = [self.jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To work with table view you need array

Checkout [this](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/) simple table view tutorial

Answer (score 0):

1. take one `NSMutuableArray` and add `dictionary` to this `array` like

   ```
   NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   [array addObject: json];

   //Than Reload Tableview

   Note: Declare array Globally to access in your class
   ```
2. `tableview` display data like

   ```
   cell.label.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"firstName"];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Store **json** data into **Global Declare NSArray**.

```
-(void)retriveFromSYSoapTool:(NSMutableArray *)_data{
    NSLog(@"data: %@",_data);
    NSArray *value = [_data valueForKey:@"GetDemoDataResult"];
    NSError *error;
    NSData *objData = [value[0] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",json);
    DataArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:json, nil];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Here **DataArray** is Globally Declare NSArray Object;

Now Write UITableView DataSource Method.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return DataArray.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"jsoncell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *dict = DataArray[indexPath.row];
    NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",dict[@"firstName"],dict[@"lastName"]];
    cell.textLabel.text = output;
    return cell;

}
```